# how to solve undefined error in react js when fetching data from API?

Tags: json, reactjs, api

> Am getting an error like TypeError landing. Slots are undefined

```
<div className="notification" />
        </header>
        <main
          style={
            ready
              ? {}
              : {
                  height: "100vh",
                  overflow: "hidden"
                }
          }>
          <LandingLoader className={ready ? "fade-out" : ""} />
          <ul
            className="slots"
            style={{
              visibility: ready ? "visible" : "hidden"
            }}>
            {landing &&
              landing.Slots.map((slot,index) => {
                if (slot && !slot.removed) {
                  let fullWidth = "100%";
                  let maxWidth = 576;

                  let style = {};
                  style["width"] = fullWidth;
                  style["maxWidth"] = fullWidth;
                  style["height"] = slot.HeightPixel + "px";

                  return (
                    <li key={index} className="slots" style={style}>
                      <Slot slotItem={slot} slotIndex={index} />
                    </li>
                  );
                }
              })}
          </ul>
        </main>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add another check for Slots e.g.

```
landing && landing.Slots && landing.Slots.map
```

Please also check, is it `Slots` or `slots`. It might be a typo error

Comment: yeah it type of error only , I tried Slots as slots also. I got same error

Comment: {
  "data":{
     "id":1,
     "lastUpdatedOn":1543843081000,
     "createdOn":1543843081000,
     "pageUID":"SLLXHJ1",
     "languageTag":"en-us",
     "type":"Home",
     "name":"Home",
     "description":"Home page",
     "slots":[
        {